# Powershell copying specific files from source directory, excluding several folders, but then recursive with wildcard for files

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Here is my current script and it works fine. Not efficient running same code twice but I don't know how to combine the wildcards... anyway on to the bigger issue.

The below code searches through my $sourceDir, excludes the files listed in $ExclusionFiles, copies all folders and structure as well as any .jpg or any .csv files, then puts them into the $targetDir.

```
$sourceDir = 'c:\sectionOne\Graphics\Data'
$targetDir = 'C:\Test\'
$ExclusionFiles = @("InProgress.jpg", "input.csv", "PCMCSV2.csv")

# Get .jpg files
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -filter "*.jpg" -recurse -Exclude $ExclusionFiles | `
    foreach{
        $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length);
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile
    }

# Get .csv files
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -filter "*.csv" -recurse -Exclude $ExclusionFiles | `
    foreach{
        $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length);
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile
    }
```

My list of files in the main $sourceDir that I need to exclude is getting longer and there are folders I want to exclude as well. Can someone tell me how to,

- Copy only a list of specific files in the $sourceDir
- Exclude certain folders in $sourceDir from copying
- Combine the wildcard search for .jpg and .csv into one statement

I'm still learning so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where a little bit of Regex will go a long way:

You can filter multiple extensions by using a pretty basic match:

```
$extensions = 'jpg', 'csv'
$endsWithExtension = "\.(?>$($extensions -join '|'))$"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
   Where-Object Name -Match $endsWithExtension
```

You can exclude a list of specific files with one more Where-Object and the -In parameter:

```
$extensions = 'jpg', 'csv'
$endsWithExtension = "\.(?>$($extensions -join '|'))$"
$ExcludeFileNames = @("InProgress.jpg", "input.csv", "PCMCSV2.csv")

Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
   Where-Object Name -Match $endsWithExtension |
   Where-Object Name -NotIn $ExcludeFileNames
```

From there on in, your Foreach-Object is basically correct (nice touch making sure the file exists by using New-Item, though I'd personally assign it's output to null and -PassThru the Copy-Item).

```
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse |
   Where-Object Name -Match $endsWithExtension |
   Where-Object Name -NotIn $ExcludeFileNames | 
   Foreach-Object {
        $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length);
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile
    }
```

Comment: Oh I like that! So pass it as a regex. Could you help me with my formatting? I am getting an error.

Comment: ```Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
   Where-Object Name -Match $endWidthExtension |
   Where-Object Name -NotIn $ExcludeFileNames
    foreach{
        $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length);
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile
    }
```
At line:10 char:12
+     foreach{
+            ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'foreach'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword